# With jQuery UI tabs, how can I run code after a click on a tab?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

With [jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/), you can use the select method to run code when a tab is clicked:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
   select: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

But the code is run before the just clicked tab has been loaded. I need to run code after new tab has been loaded. How can I do this? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
   load: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

from http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Answer (score 12):

API HAS CHANGED.
This event is now "activate"/"tasbactivate"; see http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate

----- **OLD** Answer below -----------

Based on the question it's the tabsshow (not the tabsload) event that is desired...event is triggered when a tab is shown.

Code examples: ( from http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ )

Supply a callback function to handle the show event as an init option.

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
   show: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Bind to the show event by type: tabsshow.

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "tabsshow", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

The event is useful if you want to set focus on control or similar.

Comment: This event is now "activate"/"tasbactivate"; see http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate

Comment: agreed on this answer... makes more sense for what the user is asking.

Comment: I just hate it that there is no event when you click on an active tab. It blocks the click calls but, gives you no event either

Answer (score 6):

looks like you could bind to tabsload or tabsshow:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#Events

example

```
$('#example').bind('tabsshow', function(event, ui) { ... });
```

Comment: This event is now "activate"/"tasbactivate"; see http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate

Comment: To be clear, you wouldn't use the bind() method: $( ".selector" ).tabs({
    activate: function( event, ui ) { }
});

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#job_information_tab">Job Information</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="job_information_tab">
        [content]
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('a[href="#job_information_tab"]').on('click', function() {
   alert("Don't tickle me! I am gonna pee!");
});
```